# How to delete Apache2 server

Tags: apache2, delete

How I can delete apache2 server fully?

I have installed apache2, and removed all files with purge, autoremove, and rm -rf 'whereis apache2' 'which apache2'.

And when I connect to localhost through browser I still got apache homepage.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache and reloaded the page? If so, since the program used to stop the server is probably nonexistent, have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Are you sure you dropped apache? There's a lot of packages in there, you may have missed some. Or it could be a process that wasn't killed during deinstallation?!

Comment: I'm sure that i dropped apache, and i reboot. Mistake I don't clear cache)